# Rails 4 and Devise: nested attributes validations not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am using Devise in my rails 4 app. I have a member model (for devise) and a user model that contains all the profile info for each member. A member accepts nested attributes for user. See the form below for a new registration as well as the custom routes in my routes.rb file.

My problem is this - everything works fine except validation of the user attributes. If I leave first name and last name blank, then it validates (but crashes like this:

[image]

But all the other validations for Member (the devise model) work - they end up on the /members page with the error message displayed as it should. I am unsure as to what is going on - shouldn't devise show the error messages for the invalid nested attributes?

```
class Members::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

    # GET /resource/sign_up
     def new
        build_resource({})
        self.resource.user = User.new
        respond_with self.resource
     end

    # POST /resource
    def create
        super
        resource.user.ip_address = request.remote_ip
        resource.user.email = resource.email
        resource.user.save!
    end

    private

    def sign_up_params
        allow = [:provider, :uid, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, user_attributes: [:member_id, :email, :first_name, :last_name, :institution, :city, :country, :job_title, :about, :tag_list, :picture, :ip_address]]
        params.require(resource_name).permit(allow)
    end

  end
```

Member.rb

```
  class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
      devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable, :trackable

      has_one :user, dependent: :destroy, autosave: true

      accepts_nested_attributes_for :user

  end
```

User.rb

```
  class User < ActiveRecord::Base

       belongs_to :member

       validates :first_name, presence: true

       validates :last_name, presence: true

  end
```

In my routes.rb

```
   devise_for :members, controllers: {registrations: 'members/registrations',
                                      omniauth_callbacks: 'members/omniauth_callbacks',
                                      sessions: 'members/sessions' }
```

In my members/registrations/new.html.erb

```
       <%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), html: { role: "form" }) do |f| %>

          <%= f.fields_for(:user) do |user_fields| %>

          <%= user_fields.text_field :first_name, autofocus: true, class: 'form-control', :placeholder => "First name" %>

          <%= user_fields.text_field :last_name, class: 'form-control', :placeholder => "Last name" %>

           <% end %>

       <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, class: "form-control", :placeholder => "Email" %>

       <%= f.password_field :password, class: "form-control", :placeholder => "Password" %>

       <%= f.submit t('.sign_up', :default => "Sign up"), class: "btn btn-danger" %>

       <% end %>
```

Here is the log for this

```
   Started POST "/members" for ::1 at 2015-07-16 15:18:54 +0100
   Processing by Members::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",          "authenticity_token"=>"sIxK1PTvrxNHUBdDXAtKFLLG27FvqypQ3mUvo398tHOMomi1S3I2o3vBM GwrF6PVN1NFBR5vnr8ezKP6XnMzqw==", "member"=>{"user_attributes"=>{"first_name"=>"", "last_name"=>""}, "email"=>"slfwalsh@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}
   (0.2ms)  begin transaction
   Member Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "members" WHERE "members"."email" = 'slfwalsh@gmail.com' LIMIT 1
  (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
  Rendered devise/shared/_links.erb (9.9ms)
    Rendered members/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/static_home_page (19.8ms)
    Rendered layouts/_static_login_header.html.erb (4.1ms)
     (0.1ms)  begin transaction
    (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
    Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 1499ms
```

Comment: Try `resource.user.save` instead of `resource.user.save!` in `create` method

Comment: Pavan - superb. You are correct. Make it an answer and I will mark correct. Please also give a one line explaination why this works for a newbie (like me)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why you are seeing that page is because `save!` triggers ***validation errors*** if the validation for any of the attributes is failed and those errors are displayed in the page. On the other hand `save` ***doesn't*** display the ***validation errors*** but just ***cancels the transaction*** from being saved if any of the validations are failed. Changing your create method like below should solve your problem.

```
def create
  super
  resource.user.ip_address = request.remote_ip
  resource.user.email = resource.email
  resource.user.save
end
```